# Can I use confidential information provided under an NDA for other work?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, non-disclosure, work-for-hire

Let's say that ABC Inc provided me some confidential information (CI) for a potential contract that never went through. Now XYZ Inc has approached me and asked to work on this contract with them.

Can I use (but not share with XYZ or anybody else) the information I was provided by ABC? For example, let's say that this is a proprietary communication format. XYZ only wants me to verify that the network is operating correctly and that the messages are exchanged, they do not want detailed information on the data or the format.

Both XYZ, ABC, and I are US-Based companies.

Comment: Is it ABC Inc's CI or the other contract party's CI?

Comment: What *exactly* was said in the NDA that you signed? NDAs can be very different and specify very different limitations, there's no general answer just as there's no "general NDA".

Comment: I will update this with specific language from the NDA in a couple hours when I can get to the documents. This is ABC's proprietary information for a maintenance contract originally held by ABC but now being pursued by XYZ.